# cron:remove and cron:install command is not working. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cron, command-line

I'm trying to **remove** cron but it is not working and as well on **install** as well it is not working but in case of `cron:run` it works while I run the above two commands it give me an error `C:\xamppp\htdocs\magento>php bin/magento cron:remove
Your operating system is not supported to work with this command`

Answer (score 1):

For enable Cronjob, you need to first install system cronjob and Cronjob is time-based job scheduler in Unix-like operating systems and You are using the Window system and it NOt possible run cron at the window system at this way.

You have to  use  [**Task Scheduler**](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows.html) for set magento cronjob and but cannot use `php bin/magento cron:remove` and `php bin/magento cron:install`

**You have to below command at window way:**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
```